# How to perform I/O multiplexing on non-socket FDs in Windows? (Python)

Tags: python, windows, asynchronous, select, io

I'm writing an async framework in Python, you may check that out [here on GitHub](https://github.com/nocturn9x/giambio). I have successfully implemented the basic functionality and now I need to make file I/O and hopefully make it cross-platform. I know that windows cannot handle streams that do not originate from `WinSock`  (I'm using python's `selectors` module as it has a higher-level API). I know that libraries such as trio or curio **can perform such async file I/O** on any platform. I wonder, how may I implement such a functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone does it by spawning background threads that use blocking I/O internally. The native async I/O support is just so broken and different on each OS that using threads and normal I/O is the only feasible option. Not even Linux gets it right. See the comment by njsmith https://github.com/python-trio/trio/issues/20#issuecomment-306107585

Comment: Didn't now about this! Thanks, I'll see how to structure the design of the framework then